# Are AirPlay2 device retrocompatible with AirPlay

Tags: macos, airplay, compatibility

I've a 2012 MacBook pro running MacOS 10.11. It does not have AirPlay 2 (but AirPlay is running fine).

I wonder if I buy a AirPlay2 device if they are going to work with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AirPlay 2 is backward compatible.  You can use AirPlay 2 to play to any AirPlay compatible device.

The main difference, but not the only difference, is that AirPlay is 1:1; you can play to only one device.

AirPlay 2 is 1:many; you can play from one device to multiple other devices.

[Here's](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/apple-airplay-2-everything-you-need-to-know/) a good write-up on AirPlay 2 and the benefits it brings.

Comment: I was asking the opposite. If I have a Airplay (1) Mac I don't want to upgrade to High Sierra because it'd be too slow, would it be able to connect to AirPlay 2 device ?

Comment: AirPlay 2 is backward compatible meaning that it can connect to AirPlay and AirPlay 2 sources.  If your Mac has AirPlay then any AirPlay 2 device you buy will be able to connect to it.